# Exact matches using groups in re.sub

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I am trying to change words with suffixes: "-se", "-a", "-o" or "-las", putting a blank space instead of the character "-". Example: calculou-se -> calculou se. However, I want to take only exact matches. The expected result is not being brought.

```
import re

string = " Calulou-se"
re.sub(r"^([a-zA-Z])(-)(se|a|o|las)$", r"\1 \3", string, flags = re.IGNORECASE)
# Prints:  Calculou-se
```

Answer (score 1):

The first group can repeat any number of times. So you need to fix your regex with:

```
r"^([a-zA-Z]*)(-)(se|a|o|las)$" # note the '*'
```

Or, simpler:

```
re.sub(r"-(se|a|o|las)$", r" \1", string, flags = re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: Thank you, but It is not matching in this case: string = 'calculou-se '. With your ideas I saw that this works: re.sub(r"\b([a-zA-Z]+)-(se|a|o|las)\b", r" \1 \2", string, flags = re.IGNORECASE), but this doesn't work: re.sub(r"^([a-zA-Z]+)-(se|a|o|las)$", r" \1 \2", string, flags = re.IGNORECASE). Apparently using ^...$ is not the same as using \b...\b. Thank you so much!